# Finding the stability of origin in a Lorentz system symbolically -no integer value solution

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Finding the stability of the origin fixed point in a Lorentz system.

The Lorentz equation:

$\dot{x}=\sigma\left ( y-x \right )$

$\dot{y}=rx-y-xz$

$\dot{z}=-bz+xy$

The Jacobian evaluated at the fixed point $\left ( 0,0,0 \right )$:

$J\mid _{\left ( 0,0,0 \right )}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\sigma &\sigma  &0 \\ 
r &-1  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &-b 
\end{bmatrix}$

We seek $det\left ( J \mid _{\left ( 0,0,0 \right )}-\lambda I \right )=0$

We compute the $3\times 3$ matrix:

This gives: to save you helpful souls from working it out

[image]

Setting the above result to 0, and rearranging the term to $\lambda^{3}$, $\lambda^{2}$, $\lambda$ and the constants, there is no integer valued solutions to be found.

How should I get around this conundrum?

Any explanation to expand my understanding is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375580/stability-of-origin-for-lorentz-system-and-the-nature-of-local-bifurcation-for-c) is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Don't expand the brackets. The first cofactor gives you one of the eigenvalues precisely, and the second cofactor is a simple quadratic equation which roots could be analyzed by Vieta's formula.

Comment: So the first eigenvalue is -b. The other two is solved via the quadratic equation. I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, but take into account that usually you don't need to solve quadratic equations to say something about its roots. For example, if you have equation $\lambda^2 +a \lambda + b = 0$ and $b < 0$ the roots are always real and have different signs. If $b > 0$ the roots always have the same real part the sign of which depends on $a$. It's easier to analyze the roots this way than by analyzing roots from discriminant formula.

Comment: The above was computed with Mathematica. With handworking, it's can be quite a strenuous affair to get it to the form above produced by Mathematica.

Comment: Using your second comment: The origin is a saddle node.

Comment: Saddle-node is a degenerate equilibrium with 1 zero eigenvalue (+some additional conditions which are typically hold). For what values of parameters do you want to understand the type of equilibrium?

Comment: I was about to create a new topic. But let's continue here.
The stability is always determined by the Jacobian. In $R^{2}$, this is easy enough. In $R^{3}$, this seem to pose a bit of a problem especially when it comes to verifying the stability of a fixed point. Especially in the case of a saddle node, in $R^{2}$, there is a symmetry of signs. In $R^{3}$, this symmetry is broken.

Comment: Strogaz recommends ommiting the non-linear terms together with the decoupled equation in the Lorentz equation to perform a linearisation. I take back my comment about the origin being a saddle node. I need to investigate further.

Comment: Creating new topic is a good idea, let's not mix questions here :)