# Stability of origin for Lorenz system and the nature of local bifurcation for certain control parameter

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

The Lorenz equation:

$\dot{x}=\sigma\left ( y-x \right )$

$\dot{y}=rx-y-xz$

$\dot{z}=-bz+xy$

The fixed points are $\left ( 0,0,0 \right )$ and $\left ( \pm \sqrt{\left ( r-1 \right )b}, \pm \sqrt{\left ( r-1 \right )b},r-1 \right ), \forall r>1$.

To compute the stability at the origin, Strogaz recommends removing the non-linear terms and ignoring the decoupled equation so as to perform a linearisation.

Thus,

$\dot{x}=\sigma\left ( y-x \right )$

$\dot{y}=rx-y-xz$

$\dot{z}=-bz+xy$

is reduced to

$\dot{x}=\sigma\left ( y-x \right )$

$\dot{y}=rx-y$

Now, we have:

$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\ 
\dot{y}
\end{bmatrix}$
=$\begin{bmatrix}
-\sigma &\sigma \\ 
 r&-1 
\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix}$

which from the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
-\sigma &\sigma \\ 
 r&-1 
\end{bmatrix}$

one can directly compute the trace and determinant to predict the eigenvalues and therefore the stability.

Am I in the right direction thus far?

Now, if the control parameter $r \mapsto 1$:

The non-zero fixed point for this Lorenz equation tends to $\left ( 0,0,0 \right )$.
It coalesce at the origin.

I would like to analyse and understand what the local bifurcation is for r=1. To my knowledge, it should be a **saddle-node bifurcation**, since $\left ( \pm \sqrt{\left ( r-1 \right )b}, \pm \sqrt{\left ( r-1 \right )b},r-1 \right ), \forall r>1$ and it only coalesce at the origin for r=1.

Would someone illuminate my understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To compute the stability at the origin, Strogatz recommends removing the non-linear terms and ignoring the decoupled equation so as to perform a linearization.

Well, it could be done this way, but I don't agree that it's easier.
If you want to find a linearized system for an equilibrium at the origin, it is it:
$$ \dot{x}=\sigma\left ( y-x \right ), $$
$$ \dot{y}=rx-y, $$
$$ \dot{z}=-bz ,$$
just dropping nonlinear terms. 
The linearization matrix has block-diagonal structure, and it's really easy to compute its characteristic equation and its roots. The last equation is decoupled from others and it gives this $-b$ root of characteristic equation instantaneously, and since the first two equations doesn't include $z$, you can consider them separately. I don't agree that the stability could be determined only by them unless we know something about $b$. It is true for $b > 0$, but completely false for $b < 0$ — in that case equilibrium at the origin has an eigenvalue with positive real part and it's definitely unstable.

> I would like to analyse and understand what the local bifurcation is for $r=1$.

Saddle-node bifurcation is not the only bifurcation when equilibria coalesce. In your case *three* equilibria coalesce simultaneously. As it was explained in one of the previous posts, Lorenz system is symmetric and thus this is a [pitchfork bifurcation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitchfork_bifurcation).

**ADDED LATER**: Of course, the right way to say here is that "most likely it is a pitchfork bifurcation". In case of symmetric systems this is a codimension-1 bifurcation and so it's most likely to happen. But to be completely sure you need to calculate some additional quantities. Kuznetsov book is a nice source for looking at this subject deeper, and it has many recipes that can be straightforwardly applied to generic systems, not necessarily in normal form already.

Comment: If for a Lorentz system, there exists 2 negative eigenvalues and one positive eigenvalues for an origin, how should I describe the stability? It feels as though there should be a saddle and an 'incoming' trajectory along an axis.
I take a negative and positive eigenvalue corresponding to the x and y component of a coordinate in 3-dim. Plot it on the xy-plane. Then include the z-axis through the xy-plane with trajectories tending towards the origin.

Comment: It's unstable if you have eigenvalues with positive real part. What reference book do you use?